# How to provide smoothness to 'Back to top' script using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a button with simple 'Back to top' script bound to it in JS, that gets user to the top of the page. How to add a smoothness to this movement using classic JS?

Comment: Please add your codes.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=js+smoothScroll&oq=js+smoothScroll

Answer (score 0):

Sure, here is the JS code:

```js
window.onload = function() {

 var scrollUp = document.getElementById('scrollup'); 

       

 scrollUp.onmouseover = function() { 
  scrollUp.style.opacity=0.5;
  scrollUp.style.filter  = 'alpha(opacity=30)';
 };

 scrollUp.onmouseout = function() {
  scrollUp.style.opacity = 0.9;
  scrollUp.style.filter  = 'alpha(opacity=50)';
 };

 scrollUp.onclick = function() { 
                 

        window.scrollTo(0,0);


 };

// show button

 window.onscroll = function () { 
  if ( window.pageYOffset > 0 ) {
   scrollUp.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
   scrollUp.style.display = 'none';
  }
 };
};
```

The button is an element with id="scrollup"